# Powershell ISE functions caching, how to get rid of?

Tags: powershell, caching

I've been struggling the last 2 hours on trying to kill caching of functions in the Powershell ISE. Here's a minimalistic example to demonstrate the issue:

function myFunction {
   " Monday "
}

displays: Monday

function myFunction {
   " **Tuesday** " 
} # edited, saved..

still displays: Monday

***UPDATE: figured it out..! Will still post as some others may benefit.. As it happens, Powershell is sensitive to the location of the declaration of the function vs. the call to it. It has to be AFTER.. It would be less treacherous if it simply errored out with something like "Object not found", but no, it executes nicely, if it were not for what you think is an annoying caching behavior. 
I've been scripting on Linux with Perl, which is insensitive to the functions declaration/call therefore lowering my guard..***

Comment: Please post answer and close it :)

Comment: The ISE does not "cache" functions.  What you are doing is defining a function in the *session*  and not re-defining it.

Answer (score 3):

Saving a file does not re-execute it.  Unless you reload the function binding, then it will remain in that *session* unless you restart the *session* (<kbd>CTRL</kbd><kbd>+</kbd><kbd>T</kbd> for a new session tab in ISE).

---

```
function myFunction { 'Monday' }
```

<kbd>F5</kbd>

```
PS /> myFunction
Monday
```

---

```
function myFunction { 'Tuesday' }
```

<kbd>F5</kbd>

```
PS /> myFunction
Tuesday
```